# RuntimeException when running drush commands in root folder

Tags: drush

I am setting up a local site for development on a ubuntu server 18.04 VM.
I pull our repo into my windows machine and then mount this onto the VM as a shared folder.
I run composer install and it finishes completely, but when I go to my site's docroot folder and run
drush st or drush cr, I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeException: Drush::$container is not initialized yet. \Drush::setContainer() must be called with a real container. in Drush\Drush::getContainer() (line 151 of /media/sf_anothercnas2/vendor/drush/drush/src/Drush.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Drupal installation went through successfully. In my composer.json,
I have "drush/drush": "9.7.2"

`Composer show` confirms that the local drush version installed is 9.7.2 but when I run
`drush --version`, it returns 8.1.16

Comment: So you have a globally installed Drush 8, and a locally installed Drush 9. Either replace the globally installed Drush by Drush Launcher or execute the local Drush directly as in `vendor/drush/drush/drush cr` or add the local vendor/bin to the container's PATH.

Comment: yeah, running `vendor/drush/drush/drush` did the trick. I'll look into updating Global drush. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I still am not sure why I'm getting the RuntimeException, but I can work around this issue by running

```
vendor/drush/drush/drush st //or any other drush 9 commands
```